# Java - Event How to get value without namespace (using stax)

Tags: java, xml, stax

I woudlike to write each event of xml file without namespace :

```
StringBuilder strBuilderEvent = new StringBuilder("");

while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
            //Evènement courant
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            strBuilderEvent.append(event);

}
```

I want to remove : `['http://aaa.en/ccc']:`

```
<['http://aaa.en/ccc']::idObjet>ABC</['http://aaa.en/ccc']::idObjet>
<['http://aaa.en/ccc']::thematique>10</['http://aaa.en/ccc']::thematique>
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<idObjet>ABC</idObjet>
<thematique>10</thematique>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML you're using please? This will help reproduce the problem

Comment: @YassinHajaj Ok I just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

After creating your `XMLInputFactory` with the factory method, use `setProperty` to make it non namespace aware

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, FALSE);
```

This will print results without the namespace in it